# Using datatables for wide (wide enough to go out of screen) tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTable script to convert one of the Plain HTML table (with more than 20 columns) into a good interactive one. I am also using the ColVis plugin to give user ability to make only those columns that they are interested in Visible and hide the rest. I would later be saving this selection in session Cookies so as to remember the user preference.

Problem I am currently facing with the default configuration is, as the table is wide, when the user unselects (i.e. hide) columns the table width starts reducing (as expected) but this does not move the ColVis pop up accordingly and it still remains out of the page rater than coming side wards along with the Show/Hide button. Same goes when selecting the columns back (i.e. Showing them)

I have been banging my head for a day now to find a solution for this. Any help or even pointers to areas that I should be looking at is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to reduce table width as user hides the column.

P.S.: the plug-in functionality is easy to implement using jQuery and if you do that, you will have better control over the HTML table being displayed

Comment: The table width reduces along with the Columns. The Show/Hide button also moves towards Left as the table width reduces, but the pop-up that has the Column names and the checkboxes, does not move.